# Compile Cordova / Phonegab IOS application with only 'www' file

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Just wondering is there any way to compile an IOS application using Xcode with only www file ? Because when I try to compile it, Xcode pops-up an error say that the process can't be done without Xcode project file.

Comment: you cannot compile iOS application using only www files. there is a command to build an iOS project (.xcodeproj).  use that project to compile it again.Use `cordova platform add ios` to build iOS platform and use `cordova build ios` to build the iOS project. Ref https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/

Comment: According to the link, what I need to do is just create an iOS project file using the command, then copy my www file replace the one I create using command ?

Comment: did you create a project in a place with `cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld`? https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/. if yes, just put your www file into the www folder of `com.example.hello HelloWorld` folder and execute the command that i mention

Comment: Is that work for you?

Comment: still figuring out.. maybe is the code itself having problem.. because I can compile it now using the way you taught me, but after I start the application, it just stuck at the login screen. @JackyShek

Comment: What login screen??